# How to get and set data to a particular redis database index using redisTemplate?

Tags: redis

I am using redisTemplate to get and set data to Redis. In my redis server database from (0-5) is used for other purposes.I want to store data to the Database indexed 6. How I can acheive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the select method of in the implementation fo [RedisConnectionCommands](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConnectionCommands.html) you are using:

```
redisConnection.select(6);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use RedisTemplate to query about keys and get values.
For example if you want to returns all fields and values of the hash stored at key use...

`RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    Map messageGroupMetadata = redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries("MetaData");`

Or use key to get info about a MessageGroup..

     `redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(K)`